# Reading JOptionPane input into array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input, joptionpane

```
package javaapplication3;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaApplication3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double[] temp = new Double[7];
        String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturady"};


        int i = 0;
        while (i <= days.length){

            temp[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter " + days[i] + "'s temperature in Fahrenheit."));


            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to read the inputs from the user into the temp array but I am getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error at the end of my program. Does my array size need to be adjusted or am I sending in too many inputs?

Comment: `days.length() -1`

Comment: Remember, Java arrays are 0 indexed, so you can reference positions of 0-6

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 elements in your "days" array and accordingly created an array "temp" with a size of 7 elements. But in your while loop, you iterate from index 0 to 7 (8 iterations!) and access the days array's element with that index (`while (i <= days.length) {...`).

So in the end you access element with index 7 of your days array, but since array indexes start at 0, the last index of this array is 6!

```
while (i < days.length) {...
```

Should fix your code.